# Протокол для получения потока с IP-камеры

Tags: ip, камера, web-камера

Есть задача: реализовать в реальном времени чтение видеопотока с камеры и его обработки. Программная часть будет написана скорее всего на Python (но на данный момент это не особо важно), на данный момент нужно выбрать камеру.

Вопрос в том, что на данный момент стоит задача покупки IP-камеры, с которой можно было бы снимать MPEG4 поток и, желательно, в реальном времени, а так же с поддержкой такой возможности на уровне протокола.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для максимальной совместимости со сторонним ПО берите камеру, **передающую стрим по протоколу RTSP в формате H.264** (он же MPEG-4 Part 10, он же AVC).

Этот поток можно просто транслировать «как есть» или выдавать в, например, формат [HLS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLS). Что важно, в формат HLS (и аналогичные) можно выдавать без перекодирования стрима, а просто  с его перепаковкой, что значительно менее ресурсоемко по сравнению с полноценным перекодированием.

Будет очень удобно, если камера умеет **одновременно передавать несколько стримов с разными параметрами кодирования**. Это пригодится, например, в ситуациях, когда один стрим пишется в архив длительного хранения, второй — используется для реал-тайм превью низкого разрешения, третий, максимального качества, используется для детального просмотра изображения в реальном времени.

Разумеется, можно взять камеру, выдающую наружу только один поток (максимального для камеры качества), и перекодировать его на лету во сколько угодно потоков с разными параметрами, однако надо учесть, что кодирование видеопотока в реальном времени — очень ресурсоемкий (с точки зрения процессорного времени) процесс, так что, в случае множества камер, придется выделять отдельные мощности только под перекодирование потока.

Answer (score 0):

Все ip камеры в реальном времени передают.

> Как правило, перед передачей, полученное с матрицы изображение сжимается с помощью покадровых (MJPG) или потоковых (MPEG-4, H.264) методов видеосжатия.

Comment: То есть, взяв случайную IP-камеру с полки магазина можно будет без бунда читать поток с камеры? (просто уточнить) И нет особо смысл брать камеру с поддержкой RTSP?

Comment: @users RTSP нужен для удаленного управления потоком при просмотре фильма на телевизоре через VoD.